# calling jest.spyOn "method name" parameter with a variable

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Working with Typescript and Jest, I have a class defined with a method

```
export class myAPI {
   public someMethod(){...}
}
```

and would like to invoke jest.spyOn on it, which works fine for the direct invocation like

```
jest.spyOn(myAPI.prototype, 'someMethod')
```

But when trying to provide the second parameter *method* as a variable:

```
const theMethodName : string = 'someMethod'
jest.spyOn(myAPI.prototype, theMethodName)
```

I get a `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionPropertyNames<Required<myApi>>'.`

How can I typecast it to the expected type?

Comment: `const string theMethodName = ...` isn't TypeScript. Presumably you actually have `const theMethodName: string = ...` - if you just did `const theMethodName = 'someMethod'` the type would be `'someMethod'`, which your first example shows is valid, not `string`.

Comment: You're right - I corrected the code ... and that also pointed me to the solution - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring the variable is not explicitly typed as `string`, but as `any` solved it!

Comment: Does that actually solve it, or are you just covering up a different problem?

Comment: I believe it actually solves it. In my somewhat more complex use case I use `test.each(arrayOfParams)` to dynamically run multiple tests. The parameter for  spyOn was defined in the array as a string, which didn't work - but with explicit any it works.